# How to install libnginx-mod-http-passenger on 20.04

Tags: 20.04

How could I install libnginx-mod-http-passenger on 20.04?

Comment: Why did you add an archive for bionic (18.04) on a focal (20.04) system?  The error seems valid to me

Comment: Focal (20.04) is supported by those instructions, however you needed to replace the *bionic* (ie. 18.04) with your actual release *focal* (20.04).  You didn't adapt the instructions allowing for your different release.

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry for that. I've only now got it. I've not read apt update message carefully:
`N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
`
I've only needed to add `[arch=amd64]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fix, as suggested [here](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/2263#issuecomment-637686589), is to run:

```bsh
echo "deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger focal main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list
```

Then try installing again. This will fix errors such as:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnginx-mod-http-passenger : Depends: nginx-common (< 1.14.1) but 1.18.0-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

Answer (score 7):

To install it on amd64 arch machine:

```
$ sudo apt install -y dirmngr gnupg
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 561F9B9CAC40B2F7
$ sudo apt install -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates
$ su
# echo deb [arch=amd64] https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger focal main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list
# exit
```

Then

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt-get install -y libnginx-mod-http-passenger
```

And it would be successfully installed

Comment: It works in Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS x86_64, Thanks.

Comment: This installation works in "Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS", But the nginx do not restart.